# OneToOne with shared key (MapsId) and lazy loading problem

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

My entities are:

```
@Entity
public class ReportSnapshot extends LightEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, mappedBy = "snapshot")
  private ReportContents contents;

  @Embedded
  private WeekNumber week;
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class ReportContents extends LightEntity {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @MapsId
  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  private ReportSnapshot snapshot;

  @Lob
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String reportText = "";
  ...
}
```

here light entity class comes from gilead project and is intended for gwt serialization support - it shudn't affect the process. What i observe is: when I load ReportSnapshot by id from an entity manager, I automatically get the linked ReportContents despite the lazy association. According to what I've read that shudn't be hppening as I've  set my relationship to be non-optional =(

Answer (score 1):

Which provider are you using? Hibernate [does not support lazy loading](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one) of OneToOne associations (at least not out of the box). That page documents some approaches you could try.